# How to construct a JavaScript for loop with a function

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

I'm constructing a loop for with a function.

The function `loop` takes a value, a test function, an update function, and a body function. Each iteration, it first runs the test function on the current loop value and stops if that returns false. Then it calls the body function, giving it the current value. Eventually, it calls the update function to create a new value and starts from the beginning.

```
loop(10, n => n > 0, n => n - 1, console.log);

function loop(a, b, c, d) {

    let currentValue = a;
    let i;
    for (i = 0; i < currentValue; i++) {
        if (b(currentValue)) {
            d(currentValue);
            update(c);

            function update(c) {
                var executeUpdate = c(currentValue);
                currentValue = executeUpdate;
            };
        } else {
            return;
        }
    };
}


// OUTPUT: 10, 9, 8, 7, 6
```

Why does this function stop at `6` instead of `1`?

Comment: b returns a bool, and current value is in your example int.
how does your if statement work?  `if (bool < int)`

Comment: @Fallenreaper Right, I just edited the function. Oddly the output doesn't chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function update(c) {
  var executeUpdate = c(currentValue);
  console.log('value of exeucteUpdate: ',executeUpdate, 'when i:', i)
  currentValue = executeUpdate;
};
```

Do a `console.log` at your `update` function, you will notice when `i` == 4, `executeUpdate` is 5 and you updated the value of forloop and hence the loop terminates at this particular loop

Comment: Gotcha. Anchoring the for loop check clause to a static value of a, (i = 0; i < a; i++) would fix this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use few console.logs to see it.

Actually the for-cycle ends when `currentValue` and `i` equals 5, therefore the condition is not met and cycle terminates.

However your condition does not make any sense, you are comparing `true` to some number (as you can see in the logs)

```js
loop(10, n => n > 0, n => n - 1, console.log);

function loop(a, b, c, d) {

    let currentValue = a;
    let i;
    for (i = 0; i < currentValue; i++) {
        console.log(i, currentValue);
        console.log(b(currentValue), currentValue)
        if (b(currentValue) < currentValue) {
            d(currentValue);
            update(c);

            function update(c) {
                var executeUpdate = c(currentValue);
                currentValue = executeUpdate;
            };
        } else {
            console.log('I am not here');
            return;
        }
    }
    console.log('finished', i, currentValue);
}
```

Comment: True. I just edited the condition, but oddly the output it's still the same.

> Actually the for-cycle ends when currentValue and i equals 5, therefore the condition is not met and cycle terminates.

currentValue is set as 10.